# Making Vim use capital letters when incrementing hexadecimal numbers with Ctrl-A

Tags: vim

If I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to increment (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> to decrement) a hex number, the resulting number will be written with lowercase letters, unless there were uppercase letters in the original number.

For example, if I increment `0x009`, I get `0x00a`; but if I increment `0xA09`, I get `0xA0A`.

I want it to default to using capital letters. Does anyone know how to do this? Does anyone else care?

Comment: +1 for lore of the day: `Ctrl-a` and `Ctrl-x` :)

Comment: The commands can be very useful in macros.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One tricky way:

```
:nnoremap <C-A> m'<C-A>vUgUTx``
```

Explanation:

```
m'         # Create a mark on digit to increment.
<C-A>      # Control-A
v          # Visual select current letter.
U          # Set visual selection (current letter) to uppercase.
gUTx       # Set to uppercase (gU) next movement: (Tx) from current position to previous 'x' letter.
``         # Go to position of previous mark.
```

So this way creates a small different behaviour from original `<C-A>`, for example, in this case:

```
A hex number 0x0ba in lowercase.
      ^--- Cursor position
```

Will set `0x0ba` in `0x0BB` but cursor will come back to letter `n` from `number`, insteat setting its position in the number incremented. You can play with marks to change this behaviour. I hope this can help.

Comment: I removed `m'` and `\`\`` to get it to behave more closely to the original behaviour.

Comment: I know this question is three years old, but I thought I'd point out that this solution only works if you use `<C-a>` on hex values only. As soon as you use it on a decimal number things could get messed up. I've made an addition that, admittedly is "heavier," but also more robust:
`noremap  <expr> <C-a> search('x\\|\(\<\)', "bpcn") == 1 ? "\<C-a>vUgUTxFxe" : "\<C-a>"
noremap  <expr> <C-x> search('x\\|\(\<\)', "bpcn") == 1 ? "\<C-x>vUgUTxFxe" : "\<C-x>"`

This does a search for an x to determine if it's a hex digit. If it is, it basically does what Birei has suggested. Else no capitalization.

Comment: Ugh, I accidentally pressed enter and now it won't let me edit.

I included both auto-increment and auto-decrement. This allows the auto-increment functions to be used on decimal, octal, binary, etc. without accidentally capitalizing other things on the line.

Comment: A very good approach by @Tumbler41 - it allows to use a number before <Ctrl+A> to increment multiple times. I don't know how to use it in a macro, 
though. When I record a macro and run it, only the "basic" behavior of <Ctrl+A> is executed. I suppose this is a different question, though

Answer (score 6):

One can prefix hexadecimal constants with `0X` instead of `0x` in
order to make Vim use capital letters when adding to or subtracting
from them via the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> commands.

Not a perfect solution, but oftentimes it is easier to change the
prefix of the affected number to Vim’s liking, increment or decrement
it, and then change the prefix back, than to recall how to do that in
a general way instead.

Comment: This is a good point. However I'm looking specifically for a lowercase `x` with the hex values in uppercase. I'm a bit fussy if the question didn't give it away ;)

Comment: In the end I found it much easier to use this solution and then quickly replace 0X with 0x (I was fortunate enough that it was possible). Great hint!